# no privileges on tablespace 'USERS' while my tablespace is something else

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, tablespace

I have created one table "app_config" and moved that table into a custom tablespace "appuser_tbs_initial". But whenever I try to insert values into this table I get the error "no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'". I don't understand why having a different tablespace, I am getting error for the default tablespace.
Here attaching the screenshot which could be helpful to understand my query -

[image: ora]

Comment: It might be the tablespace used by an object that depends on the table, like an index. What does this return: `select tablespace_name from dba_indexes where table_owner = 'APPUSER' and table_name = 'APP_CONFIG';`

Comment: @JonHeller By running the mentioned SQL I got "USERS" as tablespace name. Now I understand why the error came. But confused why it is not getting changed even after altering the tablespace for my table.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Jon Heller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409172/jon-heller) for giving me a clue in order to solve this. I found the actual reason behind the issue.
What I did was -

- Create a table without any custom tablespace.
- Create a primary key constraint for that table.
- Alter the table to change the tablespace to a custom one.

But I haven't altered the constraint to rebuild, So the tablespace was still the default one. After I altered the constraint and checked with the same SQL that [Jon Heller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409172/jon-heller) provided, it shows me the correct tablespace name. Now I can insert data into that table.

Comment: You may want to modify the user to default to the correct tablespace: `alter user appuser default tablespace appuser_tbs_initial;` With that configuration change you may never need to specify the tablespace again.

Comment: Yeah that helps too. Thanks @JonHeller